# MFC: how to fix "TODO <File description> (32 bit)" in task manager output?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

I use MFC to develop a win-32 app (C++). When I run it I see that it is shown as "TODO < File description > (32 bit)" in task manager and there is an arrow symbol to the left. I cannot see the real app name until I click the symbol.

Is there way to remove "TODO ..." and show the app name directly as it is?

## edit

I modify ".rc" file the following line.

```
VALUE "FileDescription", "hello_world.exe"
```

However, the task manager still displays the arrow symbol. Is it possible to show the app in one plain line without drop down?

Comment: Just do a text search in Visual Studio for `"TODO <` There is an option for searching the entire solution.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, I try your suggestion. Could you help with my follow-up edits? Thank you!

Comment: `FileDescription` doesn't show up in the Task Manager. Could you please post a screenshot of that text?

Comment: Check `LegalCopyright` and `ProductName`, it's in the same section as `FileDescription`

Comment: I suggest you could try to follow the steps: In the File Open dialog of Visual Studio, select the .EXE file and click on the arrow pointing down on the open button. Select Open With... and select Resource Editor. And then all the resource will be displayed. Here you can open the Version resource and make any changes that you like.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is related to version information and the [`StringFileInfo BLOCK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/stringfileinfo-block) statement.

In part it states:

> `FileDescription`
>
> File description to be presented to users. This string may be displayed in a list box when the user is choosing files to install—for example, "Keyboard Driver for AT-Style Keyboards". This string is required.

---

See also the related [`VERSIONINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource) resource article which also states:

> `block-statement`
>
> Specifies one or more version-information blocks. A block can contain string information or variable information. For more information, see **`StringFileInfo Block`** or `VarFileInfo Block`.

---

### How to change in IDE

You can use the **Resource View** tab to do this. You will see a **Version** tree node in there:

[image: Version Info]

Note that the Resource View is not visible by default. You can switch it on via the **View** menu. Expand **Other Windows** and it will be there. You can also use the hotkey <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>:

[image: Resource View]

---

### Manually changing the RC file

As mentioned in the comments, you can open the RC file for your project in a text editor and update the version information. For example:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Version
//

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 20,0,5,0
 PRODUCTVERSION 20,0,5,0
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x4L
 FILETYPE 0x1L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "080904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "FileDescription", "Meeting Schedule Assistant MFC Application"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "20.0.5.0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "Meeting Schedule Assistant"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright (C) 2003 - 2020"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "MeetSchedAssist.EXE"
            VALUE "ProductName", "Meeting Schedule Assistant Application"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "20.0.5.0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x809, 1200
    END
END
```

Up until now I have always used the **Resource View** tab to make my changes.